# How many games required to achieve a specific number of points (win = 1 point , loss = -1 point)

Tags: computational-mathematics

I'm not a mathematician, so hoping to get some help, I wouldn't be surprised if you all found this very trivial!

I'm playing a game that awards 1 point for a win, but subtracts a point for a loss. I'd like to know how many games I'd have to play to get to 30 points. The only data I have is my win percentage, with varies between 57% and 62%.

It's frustrating, I started recording my last 21 games. I started on 21 points and finished on 25 points after 21 games. I want to try and guess when this will come to and end!!

Appreciate the help!!

Comment: Sounds like the [Gambler's Ruin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).

Answer (score 1):

Your score after a certain number of games can be modelled mathematically as a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk). If your probability of winning each game is, say, $60\%$ then in every $10$ games you can expect (on average) to win $6$ and lose $4$. So after every $10$ games you can expect, on average, to increase your overall score by $2$. This is consistent with your experience of gaining $4$ points in $21$ games.

Your score will increase more quickly if you can increase your probability of winning each game, which will presumably happen as you get more experience. For example, if you have a $70\%$ probability of winning each game then in every $10$ games you can expect to win $7$ and lose $3$ and so your score will, on average, then increase by $4$ for every $10$ games you play.